# On Gta 5 main story I have no missions left and none are showing up... What do I do?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm pretty far in the game and I have just

> killed Trevor in a mission.
>  Then a B came up for franklin. When I got to the building franklin called Barry and then the mission just ended. I found the shrink mission after as Michael and kill dr fredlander.

But now I can't find any missions as Michael or franklin. Is there a way to get my next mission?

Comment: UHM, DAMMIT! I DIDN'T PLAY GTA 5 YET, IT GETS RELASED IN 2 DAYS, AND YOU JUST MADE ME SEE THE END. *claps*

Comment: I added spoilery part of the question in spoiler tags, as it seemed to attact a lot of negative feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You've finished the game. Outside of any activities you may have left (Strangers and Freaks, etc.) there is only the sandbox/open-world elements left to the game.